# Sampling covariance matrix using Gibbs sampling

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, gibbs

I am sampling covariance matrix from a Inverse Wishart distribution. In one dimensional case, after doing sufficient iterations I am taking the mode value for variance (after removing the burn-in values). How to do the same in a multivariate case?

Comment: 1) Do you mean Wishart or Inverse Wishart?

Comment: 2) What do you mean by "maximum occurrence"? Are you trying to find the mode (the point of highest density)?

Comment: Sorry for being vague, I have modified the question.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need a Gibbs sampler: the mode of an [inverse-Wishart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-Wishart_distribution) has a closed form.

Also, *independent* random samples from the Cholesky factor of a Wishart can be obtained from the [Bartlett decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution#Bartlett_decomposition): as it is triangular, it can be inverted easily by forward subsitution to get the Cholesky factor of an inverse-Wishart.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly:

Covariance matrix for 1-dim case reduces to the variance. Wishart Distribution (or Inv wishart distribution depending on your formulation) is a prior of covariance matrices, which for dimensions $\geq$ 2 correspond to multivariate case.

However, I may have misunderstood you. Please correct me if that is the case.

Comment: You got it correctly, it is very easy to sample a variance from the distribution (by taking out the mode value). But I am not sure how to do that in multivariate case. I am using an Inverse Wishart distribution for sampling Covariance matrix.